# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android / support / v4 / media / VolumeProviderCompatApi21 $ 1.class

Tags: android, sqlite, duplicates

I can not solve my problem.
This will make the error....

> Error: Execution failed for task ': app:
>   transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   `java.util.zip.ZipException`: duplicate entry: android / support / v4
>   / media / VolumeProviderCompatApi21 $ 1.class

The contents of my library are these and there is no duplicate file.
Please help. Thanks

```
dependencies {
    compile ('co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.3.3')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqliteassethelper.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
    compile files('libs/adad-client-3.1.jar')
}
```